# How do I make the items in "Title" column clickable?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, js

I'm trying to make **all the titles** in the column "Title" (the default title) clickable to direct me to a specific site page in SharePoint2013 as shown:

```
    <ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Title"/>
<FieldRef Name="Project"/>
<FieldRef Name="X"/>
<FieldRef Name="Y"/>
<FieldRef Name="Z"/>
  </ViewFields>
```

How do I do that using JS in SharePoint designer?

Comment: Are you using Modern UI (SharePoint Online / SharePoint 2019) or you are using Classic Experience?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela I'm using SharePoint online 2013 and SharePoint designer 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS Link to customize rendering of Title column.

**Official Documentation for JS Link:**  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/sharepoint-using-jslink-with-sharepoint-2013

You can use below Code in JS Link:

```
    (function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Title': { 'View': renderPercentComplete }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function renderPercentComplete(ctx) {

    var fieldVal = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
    var html = '<a href="{Your Link Here}">' + fieldVal  + '</a>';
    return html;
}
```

Make sure that you add Title column in your view as shown in below screen shot:

[image]

Comment: I could't find the column Title(Linked to item with edit menu), and it doesn't seem to work with the column Title.

Comment: Can you share screen shot of the view setting where you are trying to find this column?

Comment: I posted the screen shot